# Remove timestamp from date string in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I have situation where I should ignore the timestamp in a date string. I have tried the below command but with no luck.

```
"start" variable used below is in AbsTime (Ex: 01MAY2017 11:45) and not a string.

start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, '%d%^b%Y').date()
print start_date
```

My output should be :

> 01MAY2017 or 01MAY2017 00:00

Could any one help me.

Comment: `start.split()[0]` will give you the first output

Comment: Curious: where did you get the `%^b` idea from?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Might be a typo. `%` & `^` are on `5` & `6` (shift) on the regular keyboard.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil: ah, yes, that's a plausible explanation.

Comment: I want the Month in Upper case, that's the reason i used %^b.

Comment: @srisriv: there is no such modifier in Python, **and** you are using the *parsing method* (input), which shouldn't care about case.

Comment: @srisriv: see the [relevant documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

Comment: Thanks @Martijn. My start variable in the above example is in AbsTime, can you please let me know how can it be converted to a string ?

Comment: I can't. I don't know what type `AbsTime` is. Please [edit] your question to include that information, including where `AbsTime` comes from. Is it perhaps a Pandas object type?

Comment: Can you please let me know how can i use my own date object in the below code instead of 2012, 2, 23, 0, 0:      t = datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 23, 0, 0)   = > t.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

Answer (score 5):

Your directives are slightly off, and you need to capture all the contents (irrespective of what you want to retain).

```
start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, '%d%b%Y %H:%M').date()
print start_date.strftime('%d%b%Y')
# '01May2017'
```

**Update** - Adding complete code below:

```
import datetime
start = '01MAY2017 11:45'
start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, '%d%b%Y %H:%M').date()
print start_date.strftime('%d%b%Y')
# 01May2017
```

Comment: I have tried the same, but getting the below error: AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'

Comment: try `import datetime` instead of `from datetime import datetime`

Comment: Use the code in the latest answer. You might have imported `datetime` twice in the interpreter.

Comment: "TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be string, not AbsTime"

Comment: Do i need to convert AbsTime variable to a string ?

Comment: Check the updated answer. I've added the complete working code so you shouldn't face any more errors.

Comment: @srisriv: please update your question with a proper [MCVE] then that includes more detail about your actual objects. If you are not using `str` values (which your question implies), it is your job to tell us what you do have.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

To convert the string back to a datetime we can use strptime()

Example using strptime()

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('10Apr2017 00:00', '%d%b%Y %H:%M')

In [17]: datetime.datetime.strptime('10Apr2017 00:00', '%d%b%Y %H:%M')
Out[17]: datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 10, 0, 0)
```

Use strftime to form your datetime object

Example using now() returns an datetime object that we form to a string

```
datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d%b%Y')

In [14]: datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d%b%Y')
Out[14]: '10Apr2017'
```

Comment: The OP wants to retain only the day.

Comment: ... and not the current day.

Comment: that was just an example. Important part strftime

Comment: That is incorrect too. It will give `ValueError: unconverted data remains:  11:45`.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil what are you talking about?

Comment: My bad, you are using `now()` and not OP's format, so this would work.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  import datetime 
  start = '01MAY2017 11:45' 
  start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, '%d%b%Y %H:%M')
  print start_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually My Best Option to use the very same `datetime` object to subtract hours , if you do not wish to use strings and use the datetime Object itself.

Here's an Example:

```
In [1]: date.strftime('%c')
Out[2]: 'Wed Jul 10 00:00:00 2019'

In [3]: date = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

In [4]: date.strftime('%c')
Out[5]: 'Wed Jul 10 19:06:22 2019'

In [6]: date = date - datetime.timedelta(hours = date.hour, minutes = date.minute, seconds = date.second) #Removing hours, mins,secs

In [7]: date.strftime('%c') #use 
Out[8]: 'Wed Jul 10 00:00:00 2019'
```